# Syntax for macro arguments not behaving as expected

Tags: macros, tex-core

I'm trying to build some macros for parsing arguments of other macros in which I'm smuggling in hidden arguments.

The following code works perfectly:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \makeatletter

\def\ae@w@@{1}
\def\ae@m@@{1}

\def\ae@set@m@@#1/#2\ae@sep@@{\def\ae@m@@{#1}}

\def\ae@sep@wm@@#1/#2\ae@sep@@{%%
  \def\ae@w@@{#1}%%
  \ifx#2\relax\else
    \ae@set@m@@#2\ae@sep@@
  \fi
}

\def\aegetWM#1{%%
  \bgroup
    \ae@sep@wm@@#1/\relax\ae@sep@@
    W=\ae@w@@\newline
    M=\ae@m@@
  \egroup
}

\makeatother
%% to visually emphasize groupings
\setlength{\parskip}{5ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\aegetWM{400}

\aegetWM{234/100}

\aegetWM{300}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But if I defined `\ae@set@m@@` as follows:

```
\def\ae@set@m@@#1/\ae@sep@@{\def\ae@m@@{#1}}
```

I get the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
100/\relax \ae@sep@@ \fi W=\ae@w@@ \newline M=\ae@m@@ \egroup  
! Paragraph ended before \ae@set@m@@ was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.35 

?
```

What's going on here?  Why does one of these definitions work and the other not?

Comment: With the second definition, `\ae@set@m@@` *requires* `/\ae@sep@@`, while it finds `/\relax\ae@sep@@`.

Comment: also `\ifx#2\relax\else` should probably be (at least) `\ifx\relax#2\else` for safety otherwise it's true if the first two tokens in `#2` are the same rather than if `#2` is `\relax`

Comment: @egreg  Thank you.  I wasn't noticing that I had `\relax` in there.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you.  I hadn't thought about that possibility.  Duly changed. :)

Comment: You may need further precautions if 2 can be empty, otherwise you are doing \ifx\relax\else (see egreg's version:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually `\ifx\relax\else...\fi` follows the (empty) true branch, but surely it's not good programming. TeX inserts the legendary “frozen `\relax`” in this case.

Comment: @egreg so it does (my conscience was nagging me as I wrote that, I'd claim the hour except it's an hour later for you:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought that by calling `\ae@sep@wm@@#1/\relax\ae@sep@@` I was avoiding this possible issue.

Comment: @A.Ellett possibly: I didn't check all the code paths, was just looking at that one line:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say

```
\def\cs#1/\@nil{...}
```

*each* call of `\cs` must find `/\@nil` somewhere before the end of the paragraph, because the macro is not `\long`, or, if you declare it `\long`, before the end of the file currently being read.

With your second definition, you call `\ae@set@m@@#1/\relax\ae@sep@@` and TeX doesn't find the required tokens.

Actually, you're doing it in a too complicated way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\aegetWM#1{\ae@sep@wm@@#1//\ae@sep@@}
\def\ae@sep@wm@@#1/#2/#3\ae@sep@@{%
  W=#1\newline
  M=\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax1\else#2\fi
}
\makeatother
%% to visually emphasize groupings
\setlength{\parskip}{5ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\aegetWM{400}

\aegetWM{234/100}

\aegetWM{300}

\end{document}
```

Let's look what happens when you call `\aegetWM{400}`:

```
\ae@sep@@wm@@ 400//\@ae@sep@@
```

so `#1<-400`, `#2<-<empty>`, `#3<-<empty>`. When you call `\aegetWM{234/100}` we get

```
\ae@sep@@wm@@ 234/100//\@ae@sep@@
```

so `#1<-234`, `#2<-100`, `#3<-/`.

Comment: So `\detokenize{#2}` resolves to `\relax` if the second argument is empty?  In other words, `\detokenize{}`=`\relax`?

Comment: @A.Ellett No, `\detokenize{}` produces nothing at all. If the second argument is empty you get `\if\relax\relax` which is true. Otherwise you get `\if\relax<first char in the argument (detokenized)>` which is surely false.

Comment: So I'm a bit confused by the comments from you and David to my original post about the bad programming.  Isn't it the same either way?  I'd prefer not to program badly, but I'm not seeing where the difference is here.

Comment: @A.Ellett `\ifx\relax\else` or `\if\relax\else` is bad programming. With my code you can't get something like that: it's `\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax<T>\else<F>\fi`; even if `<T>` is empty you can't get the "bad guy".

Comment: Now I see.  Thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: Why not write `\ifx\relax#2\relax....\fi`?  What benefit is `\detokenize` providing?

Comment: If `#2` starts with `\relax` your conditional would be true, with `\detokenize` it's false. So with `\detokenize` the conditional is true only if `#2` is really empty.